# Closed BezierCurve is cut in exported PDF or EPS

Tags: graphics, bugs, export, pdf-format, splines

**Bug introduced in 10.3 or earlier and persisting through 11.1.0 or later**

---

`Export`ing the filled Bézier curve to PDF or EPS yields

```
pts1 = {{3, 0}, {-1, 3}, {1, -5}, {5, -1}, {3, 0}};
test = Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Black], GrayLevel[0.8], 
    FilledCurve[BezierCurve[pts1, SplineDegree -> 4]]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.6, 3.6}, {-1.8, 1.}}, Frame -> False]
Export["i.pdf", test] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

In the notebook it renders correctly as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The export to EPS and PDF, thought, remains broken. Exporting to raster formats works correctly.

Comment: Do you see this only when exporting or also in the notebook?  This is what I see in the notebook in M version 10.0 or later, but not in version 9.0.  What Mathematica version are you using?

Comment: I edited your question, please review it. I removed any references to exporting because I could not verify that there is a difference between export and in-notebook rendering.  I tried this on OS X. Please check again, and add the necessary information: is export really different? What version, what OS?  Then we will have collected more diagnostic info.

Comment: Since I made a very substantial edit to your post, it is important that you review it and correct what is necessary. Could you do that please?

Comment: @Szabolcs I use 10.3. In the notebook it renders correctly. Only export is broken. Exporting to raster format and then importing and reexporting again to vector format, of course, helps (it then contains points only objects).   OS is Ubuntu Linux, 14.03, (32 bit edition).

Comment: Thanks! Could you integrate all the information we have so far into the post?

Comment: I am running V11.0.1 on OS X 10.10.2. The graphic object is rendered correctly in the notebook and when saved into PDF file using the notebook menu commands. When I export it using `Export`, I get the broken version.

Comment: I would call this a bug in `Export` on OS X. The display rendering appears to be corrected in V11.0.1 if it was broken in earlier versions.

Comment: With Mma 11.0.1 and macOS Sierra 10.12.3 I get the "truncated" image in the notebook

Comment: I observe the cut closed Bézier curve in `Export`ed PDF file in versions 10.4.1, 11.0.1 and 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64. With version 8.0.4 it is exported correctly. Rendering inside of the Notebook is OK in the all tested versions.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed in V13.0.1 or earlier:

```
pts1 = {{3, 0}, {-1, 3}, {1, -5}, {5, -1}, {3, 0}};
test = Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Black], GrayLevel[0.8], 
    FilledCurve[BezierCurve[pts1, SplineDegree -> 4]]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.6, 3.6}, {-1.8, 1.}}, Frame -> False]
Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "i.pdf"}], test] // SystemOpen
```

[image]

Comment: Appears to be fixed from version 12.0.0.